# compressing java heap -

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have a problem - I have 32-bit windows machines and applications that reach the heap upper bound. I get an OutOfMemoryError.

I cannot reduce the memory.

I am looking into some ability/module to compress the heap somehow to save memory.

I found this article about phones:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=1425112&contentType=Conference+Publications

I am looking for a product, similar, to the one above but for PC.

Thank you.

Comment: java -Xmx <more memory>?

Comment: Do you have 4GB of RAM / virtual disk? If you have less than that just buy more RAM. Otherwise it would be better to improve the software you are using or break up the work you are doing into smaller chunks so that you don't run out of memory. If you are really hitting the 4GB limit, compression will not help as you'll need pointers longer than 32 bits to use above 4gb

Comment: Have you checked SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java?

Comment: Yes, but java 32-bit limits you to 1200-1400 MB.

Comment: IIRC, you can run a 64-bit Java VM on a 32-bit machine.  That would let you increase the heap size cap.

Comment: Hi, Louis. I also have 32-bit dlls. Will this work? Thank you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I find that very unlikely. Other way around, sure. If it was true why would they bother providing both?